# How to if elase function for following?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need help to create function to enable option disable other remaining options. For suppose id product price is fall between 5000 to 10000 then it allows to choose only option that has 5000 to 10000 and remain will disable and Price in between 10000 to 20000 and it only allow respictive option to choose.
[image: Options dom]

[image: option filed for user]

[image: Price of product]

If above price fall between the slab rates mentioned in options inner text then it should enable and remaining disabled.

Comment: But it actually disable all the options

Comment: it wouldn't if you put the condition in the correct place

Comment: I need sample with two prices. Can any one provide?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone

Answer (score 0):

When you loop over to generate the dom, check `if (price > min && price < max)` to determine if to set a disabled on the option.

Or do after with jQuery, which question suggests

```js
const minPrice = 1000
const maxPrice = 10000

$('.product-custom-option option').each(function() {
  const price = Number($(this).attr('price'))
  if (price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice) {
    $(this).removeAttr('disabled')
  } else {
    $(this).attr('disabled', true)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="product-custom-option">
  <option price="100">100</option>
  <option price="500">500</option>
  <option price="1000">1000</option>
  <option price="5000">5000</option>
  <option price="10000">10000</option>
  <option price="50000">50000</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am getting the price from "var price = document.querySelector("span.price").innerText;"

Comment: ok, is that not working? if its not kindly, update your question with all the code your trying

Comment: If that price fall in between the value mentioned in text of the option not in price attribute, i need to enable

Comment: you cant get a `min` and `max` range from a single value unless you do derive a second value from it which has fudged +/-

Comment: If the price is 8000 , i need to enable value attribute that has 566,567 and if the price of product is 12000 then i need to enable the attribute value that has 568,569.

Comment: Please don't consider price attribute

Comment: you need price attribute on the dom so js can pick it up in js, else you need to parse from the options text which is more code and error-prone depending on the language, currency format etc then just placing it on the dom, else you need to do all logic serverside not with jquery, as product id 566 has no idea about the price unless you expose the price value somewhere on something you can loop over, like price attr on the option

Comment: on other note, if you want to show all things from `0` to `n` (price) its `if (price <= itemPrice)` is just basic logic, like wise if you want to show all that are above then `if (price >= itemPrice)` or anything in between as shown above

Comment: I will give max and min values manually , price taking from product price and then compare with min and max and then enable certain option based on above.

Comment: $('.product-custom-option option').each(function() {
  const price = Number($(this).innerText);
  if (price >= 5001&& price <= 10000) {
    $(option.value=566 & option.value=566  ).attr('enabled')
  } else {
    $( option.value=568 & option.value=569  ).attr('disabled', true)
  }
})    @LawrenceCherone